# d3 js .append("line") doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to put a place holder for my x and y axes for a graph I'm going to make, but the lines aren't showing up. I was able to draw an eclipse on the same svg I'm using here, but for whatever reason the lines just don't show.

```
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300);

console.log("window width" + window.innerWidth/2);

line = svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1",300)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr('x2', 0)
  .attr("y2", 300)
  .attr("stroke-width", 5)
  .attr("fill", "black");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lines have no width and cannot be filled. You want stroke rather than fill.

```js
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300);

console.log("window width" + window.innerWidth/2);

line = svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1",300)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr('x2', 0)
  .attr("y2", 300)
  .attr("stroke-width", 5)
  .attr("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works when I put it on js fiddle along with my other code, but it doesn't work on the browser. Would there be any reason why?